# Show toast within try-catch block

Tags: android, try-catch, toast

I am new to android programming and trying to develop a simple app where I am trying to send email by using a try catch block as shown below:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    try {       
        GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("username@gmail.com","password");
            sender.sendMail("Test mail","This mail has been sent from android app along with attachment","username@gmail.com","Someuser1@gmail.com");
            } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}).start();
```

From the above code when the email sending is failed I get an error displayed using toast.
But Now I would like to know If the mail is sent successfully I need to display the toast

This is what I have tried but the app is getting crashed and unable to display any toast

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    try {       
            GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("username@gmail.com","password");
                sender.sendMail("Test mail","This mail has been sent from android app along with attachment","username@gmail.com","Someuser1@gmail.com");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

can anyone guide to the right way of doing this to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use  the below code to show toast put the ui related contents within UI thread

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
public void run() {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
});
```

Comment: @Arju-First thanks for your reply..And can you say me what does the above code do ? and where does this code actually go ?

Comment: The above code is a thread as u used, but the difference is it is an UI thread, Since toast is related to UI you need such a thread

Comment: ok. but I need to get a success message after sending it but not the error message.

Comment: Change the text within the toast, actually you can put the code within a method and call the method by passing the message Eg: ShowToast("Success");

Comment: Got it :) Thanks Arju for your time

Answer (score 1):

Just to Make **Viswanath Lekshmanan** answer more clear to Android Newbies

```
try{

runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
public void run() {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success Message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
});

}catch() {

runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
public void run() {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
});

}
```