# Null Pointer Exception after creating Toast in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I am trying to show a Toast when my API-Request doesn't work due to No-Internet-Connection.
To start of easy, I just tried to show a Toast as soon as the try-block fails and then I want to show the Toast in the catch-block.
I tried the approach from developer.android.com but I can't even start the Application.

My code in the catch-block is this:

```
} catch {
Context context = getApplicationContext();
Toast.makeText(context, "No Internet Connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I seem to have problems with the `getApplicationContext()` Method, because this is highlighted red.
It seems to be a problem because I am using this Inside a Fragment. I read something with using `Activity activity = getActivity()` but when trying to insert this `activity` as the context in the `makeText()` Method, I get this Error Message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4
    Process: com.example.dhapp, PID: 16158
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't toast on a thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
        at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:157)
        at android.widget.Toast.getLooper(Toast.java:287)
        at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:256)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:891)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:879)
        at com.example.dhapp.SearchFragment$apiThread.run(SearchFragment.java:112)
```

Any tips on how I get this to work? Thanks a lot in Advance!

Comment: The code you posted has a typo: it should be `getApplicationContext()` but you posted `getApplicationcontext()`. Perhaps that's why the method is highlighted red. As for the exception, that may be because you are executing the `catch` block in a worker thread. You'd have to post more code and an explanation of what you're doing for us to help you with that.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875184/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare

Comment: check here [Show toast within try-catch block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177023/show-toast-within-try-catch-block)

Comment: check @srinij 's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are NOT calling the `Toast.makeText()` from within the main thread. The thread that you call from needs access to the UI essentially for the Toast to display.

[This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875184/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare) might give you some pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You CANNOT show a Toast on non-main thread. You need to call Toast.makeText() (and most other functions dealing with the UI) from within the main thread. You can find some solutions on
[Can't toast on a thread that has not called Looper.prepare()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47536005/cant-toast-on-a-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare),
[How do you display a Toast from a background thread on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134683/how-do-you-display-a-toast-from-a-background-thread-on-android)

The problem with the `getApplicationContext()` is that you are inside a fragment you should get The activity context this way

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No Internet Connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The getContext() method it's implemented on Fragments.java so you dont need to call `getApplicationContext()` because it is only available from activities not from fragments.

```
   /**
     * Return the {@link Context} this fragment is currently associated with.
     *
     * @see #requireContext()
     */
    @Nullable
    public Context getContext() {
        return mHost == null ? null : mHost.getContext();
    }
```

Comment: this is not a correct answer to the Question posed, the issue is that Toast is not being called from the Main thread

Comment: yes it's true i edit my answer but he also have problems with the getApplicationContext(); method

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using getApplicationContext() you could try requireActivity()